Packages for Big Panel Data Regression in R
Is it possible to run a regression on a panel data set with 10,000 objects ($N$), each with $2,000$ observations (time series length $T$)? If so, what package in R can handle this?

At the time of this writing, hands down the fixest package in R is at the top of the food chain, with the plm package vying for that position but falling somewhat short, in my very humble opinion.
I would be less concerned with the functionality of the package and more concerned with your machine. If your local computer has 16 gigabytes of RAM or less, then expect poor performance with a panel containing 20 million rows ($N \times T = 20,000,000$). Consider working with smaller subsets of your data (i.e., chunks), if possible, so your processing speed isn't severely compromised.
I also suggest perusing the CRAN Task View on High-Performance and Parallel Computing.

So you still recommend plm package, right?

While it may not be my first choice, I’d still recommend it.

I can see, thanks!
